# Which is better description between has_many / belongs_to and has_many through on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-schema

In Rails, what is the difference between the `has_many` / `belongs_to` relationship and `has_many :through => "table_name"`?

Comment: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the difference is that in `has_many`/`belongs_to` there are two models in relation to each other - for example:

Phone_book.rb

```
has_many :contacts
```

Contact.rb

```
belongs_to :phone_book
```

A phone book can have any number of contacts, but any one of those given contacts belongs to a particular phone book.

In a `has_many :through` relationship there are three models - here's a good example from the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

[image: has_many :through]

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons on both sides.

### HABTM

The main advantage is the convenience. You don't have to worry about the relationship table, rails 'hides' this for you.

### Has many through

Has many through: The main advantage is the flexibility. In case you realize that you need to add more details to the 'relationship' later on, you can just add them to the relationship table.

### Example

Lets take an example to illustrate this problem. Lets say we want to identify which users speak what languages. So, we write User HABTM Language. All goes fine for a while. Then there is a requirement to know, which of those languages is the user's native language and if it is not the native language.

At this point, you could either add 'native_language' field to the user or you could enhance the 'user speaks language' relationship to add 'is_native' flag to it. If you want to add such a flag, you need to convert the HABTM into a has-many-through relationship.

Comment: OP isn't asking about has_and_belongs_to_many relationship